# Xcode git add files

Tags: xcode, git

Is there anyone ever come across with this issue as follows...?

When u add files to your project, and the Xcode git will indicate a "?" as the badge. So, according to what I know about the meaning of the badge is because GIT could not find the file.

Answer (score 2):

```
Right click > Source Control > Add
```

Comment: All my options after Source Control > ... are greyed out. What does this mean?